# FCC Parameters in SAP PI

Tags: integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

Is there any way to display Recordset Structure Sequence in Ascending Order?

In the existing configuration of File Adapter's Content Conversion Tab of File Content Conversion, we have Recordset Sequence : Ascending/Variable. But I wish to arrange the Recordset Structure in Ascending Order.

Is there any fcc parameter for this task?

Current Structure:

`RecordSet -->RecordSet Structure(1) -->RecordSet Structure(3) -->RecordSet Structure(2)`

Desired Output:

`RecordSet -->RecordSet Structure(1) -->RecordSet Structure(2) -->RecordSet Structure(3)`

Answer (score 0):

When using mtb there is a pararmeter called: `xml.recordsetStructureOrder = asc`.

When using `fcc` there should be a similar parameter after the setup.